# LiteDB Multiple Column/Field ID

Tags: c#, nosql, bson, litedb

I have a class that has multiple fields.
Lets say for example:

```
class MyClass {
    public int x {get; set;}
    public int y {get; set;}
    public int z {get; set;}
}
```

I want to use LiteDB with that class, and have it use both x and y as a key.
So for example:

```
MyClass{x: 0, y: 0, z:0}
MyClass{x: 0, y: 1, z:0}
```

Will be considered as 2 different entries in my LiteDB database.

So I basically want something like this:

```
var mapper = BsonMapper.Global;
mapper
    .Entity<MyClass>()
    .Id(c => new {c.x, c.y});
var db = new LiteDatabase("PATH_HERE", mapper);
```

Obviously, Id(c => new {c.x, c.y}); doesnt work. I've also tried

```
.Id(c => c.x)
.Id(c => c.y);
```

But it doesn't work either. I've tried looking for a solution in the LiteDB documentation, but was unable to find anything. Is this possible? If so, I would love to understand how to achieve my goal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `BsonDocument`, `_id` must be a single value, there is no compound key. But this value can be another document. So, you can use this:

```
class MyId {
    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }
}

class MyClass {
    public MyId Id { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can find using

```
col.Find(x => x.Id = new Id { x = 0, y = 1 })
```

Comment: Thanks. I hoped to avoid editing MyClass. Also, some info that was supposed to be stored in the key, the MyClass instance was supposed to be unaware of. I ended up using a new field key, and searching by rest of the fields.

Comment: So `.FindById()` would not be used in this circumstance? and the `.Find(predicate)` version automatically uses the PK index?

Comment: `FindById` requires `BsonValue` and there is no direct conversion from your class to `BsonValue`. To use find by id, you must use bsonmapper too: `FindById(mapper.ToDocument<MyClass>(new Id { x = 0, y = 1 }))`